# How to prove $0\le a$ for all $a$ in the natural number?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Some of the definition I used in my proof:

**Definition 2.2.11 (Ordering of the natural numbers).** Let $n$ and $m$ be natural numbers. We say that $n$ is greater than or equal to $m$, and write $n\ge m$ or $m\le n$, iff we have $n=m+a$ for some natural number $a$. We say that $n$ is strictly greater than $m$, and write $n>m$ or $m<n$, iff $n\ge m$ and $n\neq m$.

**Corollary 2.2.9.** If $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers such that $a+b=0$, then $a=0$ and $b=0$.

This is my proof:

Suppose to the contrary there exists a natural number $a$ such that $a<0$. By **Definition 2.2.11** there exists a natural number n such that $0=a+n$ and $a\neq 0$. But by **Corollary 2.2.9.** we must have $a=0$ and $n=0$, a contradiction. Therefore $0\le a$ for all natural numbers $a$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Is $0$ a natural number?

Comment: @311411 Brrrr.. $0$ is not a natural number.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to mention that my book Analysis by Terence Tao assumes 0 to be a natural number.

Comment: @joji0001 Ohh okay, Everything else is fine in your proof. Well done!

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Comment: Is $a+0=a$ in your axiom set? If it is, then the proof can be shorter. Anyway, the proof as it is, is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect. You are attempting to prove that $0 \leq a$.

Your first step is supposing to the contrary that $a < 0$. You are implicitly asserting that $a < 0 \iff \neg (0 \leq a)$ in order to use this proof by contradiction. But nowhere have you proved this, and it is not immediate from the definition of $<$.

You then say that because $a < 0$, by the definition of $<$, there must be some $n$ such that $0 = a + n$ and $n \neq 0$. Again, you are making an assertion without proving it. The assertion that you’re making is $n \neq 0$, but you haven’t cited any fact to justify this.

The correct proof is simply: note that $a = 0 + a$ (by the axioms governing $+$). Therefore, there is some $b$ such that $a = b + a$; namely, $b = 0$. Then by the definition of $\leq$, $0 \leq a$.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks!

Comment: @joji0001 If Mark's work solves your problem, you should "Accept" the answer by clicking the Check-Mark, so it turns green. You may also vote up, as I have done.

Comment: When descending to the sub-basements of analysis, it is so easy to bring with us "basic facts" from the higher levels --- inappropriate ones! I okay-ed the move $a < 0 \iff \neg (0 \leq a)$ without any hesitation. Whoops.